# Function called without onClick from Button

Tags: python-3.x, function, tkinter

I was trying to return the result from a function after a button is triggered. But it happens that the function was called once I run the project.

```py
def main_execute():
    result = 0;
    return result

# Button
main_execute_btn = tk.Button(
    window,
    text='Execute',
    height=5,
    width=15,
    activebackground='grey',
    activeforeground='blue',
    bd=3,
    command=main_execute
)

main_execute_btn.place(relx=0.8, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

result_str = IntVar(window, main_execute())

# Text String
main_result_ts = tk.Label(
    window,
    textvariable=result_str).place(relx=0.8, rely=0.8, anchor=CENTER)
```

Please ignore the input boxes.

[image]

The `main_result_ts` shall return `1` after the `main_execute_btn` is clicked.

Comment: You are calling the function early in `result_str = IntVar(window, main_execute())`.

Comment: how shall i write to declare the IntVar to retrieve result from function after button clicked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can simply change the value of the Label `main_result_ts` by using the `.config` command in the following way:

`main_result_ts.config(text = result)`

Also, I think you have forgotten to write `window.mainloop()` at the end of your code.

According to your post, you have mentioned that you want `main_result_ts` to display 1 after clicking `main_execute_btn`. For this you have to declare ``` result`` outside the function ``` main_execute()``` and to change its value within the function, use the following code:

```
def main_execute():
    global result
    result += 1;
    return result
```

Comment: I follow your suggestion and it works. 

`def main_execute():
    result = 0;
    main_result_ts.config(text = result)`